# Persisting docker container logs in kubernetes

Tags: docker, logging, kubernetes, containers, rsync

I’m looking for a really simple, lightweight way of persisting logs from a docker container running in kubernetes. I just want the stdout (and stderr I guess) to go to persistent disk, I don’t want anything else for analysing the logs, to send them over the internet to a third party, etc. as part of this.

Having done some reading I’ve been considering a DaemonSet with the application container, but then another container which has `/var/lib/docker/containers` mounted and also a persistent volume (maybe NFS) mounted too. That container would then need a way to copy logs from the default docker JSON logging driver in `/var/lib/docker/containers` to the persistent volume, maybe rsync running regularly.

Would that work (presumably if the rsync container goes down it's going to miss stuff because nothing's queuing, perhaps that's ok rather than trying to queue potentially huge amounts of logs), is this a sensible approach for the desired outcome? It’s only for one or two containers if that makes a difference. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to use a logging moudle to dump conosle logs to a file and that file should be on a shared persistent mount?

Comment: I think I could override Dockerfile RUN/CMD to redirect output to file, that could work. Not sure about log rotation then though. Is that a usual pattern?

Comment: I wouldnt say a usual pattern but for the small use case i think this would do, since you dont want to use log collectors like fluentd etc. But doing it from the code itself would be better since you can use built in log handlers for log rotation etc. simple redirecting logs from dockerfile run seems to be a bit non standard. But again if its a small use case as you said, then i think you could go with this.

Answer (score 1):

Fluentd supports a simple file output plugin (https://docs.fluentd.org/output/file) which you can easily aim at a PersistentVolume mount. Otherwise you would configure Fluentd (or Bit if you prefer) just like normal for Kubernetes so find your favorite guide and follow it.